# How can I do to fix the jquery portfolio error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with the implementation of a portfolio in a single page. 
The portfolio that I enter this code has

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $('#work').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      controlsContainer: '.flex-container'
    });

    //Add one flexslider for project
    $('#proj_slider01').flexslider();
    $('#proj_slider02').flexslider();
    $('#proj_slider03').flexslider();
    $('#proj_slider04').flexslider();
    $('#proj_slider05').flexslider();
    $('#proj_slider06').flexslider();
    $('#proj_slider07').flexslider();
    $('#proj_slider08').flexslider();
    $('#proj_slider09').flexslider();
});
```

Unfortunately I can not publish all the code of a website done in a single page. So if you want to see the site the link is http://goo.gl/W2Xq7 and can find the real portfolio in this link http://goo.gl/jgD3o. If you don't understand where il the problem, you can ask me the link for the source code.
Where is the problem in my site and how can I do to fix it?

Comment: I don't understand where your problem is because you haven't gone further than "I have a problem". There's nothing wrong with a bit of detail.

Comment: You can't show us the code, and you don't explain the problem. ...without more detail this *will* (and *should*) be closed as 'not a real question.'

Comment: see the portfolio in the first link? do not open the cards as they should be open in the second link in our work section.

Comment: As a side note, `$("[id^='proj_slider']").flexslider()` can replace all others.

Comment: @pimvdb I tried but not solved

Comment: No - it was a suggestion meant as a side note. They should behave the same (so it doesn't solve anything).

Answer (score 1):

You are loading jQuery more than once into page. The scond version wipes out plugins that are attached to first version. Only load jQuery.js one time, and load it before all plugins and dependent code

Comment: Ok, but if i remove for example the second loading Jquery doesn't work the menu in the single page.

Comment: I tried removing first the jquery-1.7.1.min.js and the portfolio doesn't work, then i've tried removing jquery.min.js and the portfolio work but doesn't work the menu and the botton TOP

Comment: Now you can see the link on-line http://goo.gl/W2Xq7 with the changes that you told me. As you will see the portfolio now works in the middle while the top menu of the site does not work.

Comment: Now I have restored the old version

Comment: i don't know if you are combining pages on server or not...but your problems are all due to needing only one version to load

Comment: ok now I've uploaded the two versions by eliminating a first loading and then the other http://goo.gl/Ejb1m http://goo.gl/GhBcn